# Django ConnectionAbortedError + TypeError + AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I am using Python 3.6.0 + django 1.11 + windows 7 64 bit

my website is running fine but I am keep getting this errors.

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host machine
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Why i am getting this ..? and how to fix these errors ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[18/Sep/2017 12:25:10] "GET /api/dashboard/workorder_list/6/?format=json&_=1505708684218 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 32251)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: it's trying to 'split' on a None object, which in your case is 'self.status'
So, your response object doesn't have a status for some reason... is it that you don't set it (not sure, it should default to 200) or you set it to some invalid value maybe and it gets stripped out... you need to do some more digging...

Comment: you should use exception handling in your code...

Comment: You may have encountered a [known Python Bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue27682).

Comment: Is this triggered by an ajax call from the client? What is triggering this?

Answer (score 1):

This has now been fixed in Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713

It will be available in the next version of Python 3.7 and later.